# SwiftUI Form Validation using RXSwift?

Tags: ios, validation, swiftui, rx-swift

I'm building a native IOS app using SwiftUI. I should use RXSwift to validate some fields of a form live, before the user clicks a button. In particular, I would need the validation checks on a text field, on a date, on a numeric field and on an email field.

Excuse me if the question is a bit generic, but I'm a beginner with applications.

Could someone please explain me how I could do the validation using SwiftUI and RXSwift? If you had any examples, it would be perfect.

Thanks in advance for your kindness!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm going to go against the grain and say that you probably shouldn't be using Libraries, in particular `RxSwift` while trying to learn SwiftUI. Learning application development should be learned from a strong foundation, not from blocks of code already pre-built. Understanding concepts and fundamentals will help you tremendously as you pickup this skill. With that being said, my opinion is that RxSwift is nothing more than a crutch, SwiftUI already has everything you need and does it in a simple way.

Regarding your actual question, I'm assuming you don't know how to validate at all within SwiftUI, so I'll attempt to answer this the best I can and explain along the way.

#### View Example

```
struct TestView: View {
    @ObservedObject var testModel = TestModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            
            Text(testModel.isTextFieldValid() ? "Valid" : "Not Valid")
            
            TextField("Some Text", text: $testModel.textFieldText)
        }
    }
}
```

There are a few key things to pay attention to on our `View Example` firstly, notice the `@ObservedObject` that object is our `ViewModel` that we have created below. it's how we tie all of our data to our view. It's also how we `Bind` our data. Much like `RxSwift` if we change our view, our model is updated, if we change our model, our view is also updated.  In this `View Example` I have a text field that is tied to a function `.isTextFieldValid()` which is how I'm checking if the text is valid or not. Now you can get into all sorts of different validation techniques but it's all use case. You might simply be validating for empty, certain characters, length, or any number of conditions you might be looking for. I have a field that is also tied to the view model's `textFieldText` property which the method checks against.

#### View Model Example

```
class TestModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var textFieldText = "Hello"
    
    func isTextFieldValid() -> Bool {
        textFieldText.count > 0
    }
}
```

In the view model, which is an `@ObservableObject`, I have a `@Published` property, textFieldText. The view's `Text()` is bound to this value in it's second argument, eg `text: $testModel.textFieldText` where any text entered is sent to that property on the model. This is where it gets interesting. Anytime a `@State` or  `@ObservedObject` is updated, the entire view is re-drawn. That's why the function here, `isTextFieldValid()` doesn't need to be `@Published` because the textFieldText is updated, the view is redrawn, and this method is called again. As a result it will check. In my example I'm simply validating if the text field contains more than 0 characters. Using this same principal you can easily see how `RxSwift` provides no benefits over SwiftUI's native tools. If you build this simple example you'll see "Live Validation" that you're expecting as you type into the text field.

Comment: Yea, when working with SwiftUI. I think the OP should use Combine rather than RxSwift. Combine was specifically introduced to support reactive programming with SwiftUI.

Comment: To be graced with the presence of the top 1% er on stack overflow. Hello @DanielT.

Comment: Add the `rx-swift` tag to a question and I'll be there. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much, your response has been really helpful!